# Initialize Jenkins with Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

I am building Jenkins with a Dockerfile, and during the Docker build I would like to have Jenkins pre-configured with a set of jobs.  I find this works well with Jobs DSL, where jobs are seeded, but I have yet to preconfigure the "Pipeline" DSL.  Given the direction of Jenkins and use of Jenkisfile, Pipeline, etc, I think there must be some way to allow Jenkins to automatically run with a set of jobs that were built using the Pipeline approach

Example Pipeline:

```
    pipeline {
        agent { 
            label 'cft'
        }
parameters {
        string(name: 'StackName', defaultValue: 'cft-stack', description: 'The name to give the CFT stack.')
        string(name: 'KeyName', defaultValue: 'ACCOUNT', description: 'The account key to use for encryption.')
        string(name: 'VpcId', defaultValue: 'vpc-1234', description: 'The VPC to assign to the cluster resources.')
        string(name: 'SubnetID', defaultValue: 'subnet-1234, subnet-6789', description: 'The subnet(s) to assign to the cluster resources.')
    stages {

        stage('Build') {

            steps {

               s3Download(file:'cft.yaml'
                    , bucket:'cft-resources'
                    , path:'cft.yaml'
                    , force:true)

                cfnUpdate(stack:"${params.StackName}"
                    , file:"cft.yaml"
                    , params:[
                    "SnapshotId=${params.SnapshotId}",
                    "KeyName=${params.KeyName}",
                    "VpcId=${params.VpcId}"
                    ]
                    , timeoutInMinutes: 20
                )
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            echo 'FAILURE'
            cfnDelete(stack:"${params.StackName}")
        }
    }    
}
```

Dockerfile:

`COPY ./groovy/*.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/`

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline's Groovy files differ from the Groovy code that can be executed to configure Jenkins. You can't add pipelines the way you're trying to do.

Your options include

- copy the XML file for the job definition (pointing to your repo, as the pipeline should be in the `Jenkinsfile` in the repo)
- create a job using Groovy and configure it (not really practicable IMHO)
- use [JobDSL](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) (again, with XML as starting point) to specify your Jenkins jobs. An example for automatically adding this can be found in [tknerr/jenkins-pipes-infra](https://github.com/tknerr/jenkins-pipes-infra).